# Align two pickers in a LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I am doing Fragment with picker elements. I have two pickers (NumberPicker and TimePicker) in a LinearLayout and I want to align them.

This is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

  <LinearLayout 
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:orientation="vertical">

    <Switch
    android:id="@+id/buscar_instalaciones_horario_fragment_switch1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView                
    android:id="@+id/buscar_instalaciones_horario_fragment_tv_subtitulo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:text="@string/del_14_de_junio_al_31_de_agosto"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

 </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout 
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_weight="1"
 android:gravity="center_horizontal">

   <RadioGroup 
    android:id="@+id/buscar_instalaciones_horario_fragment_radiogroup"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <RadioButton 
            android:id="@+id/buscar_instalaciones_horario_fragment_radiobutton_abierto"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Apertura"
            android:checked="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <RadioButton 
            android:id="@+id/buscar_instalaciones_horario_fragment_radiobutton_cerrado"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cierre"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>           
   </RadioGroup>


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

        <NumberPicker
                    android:id="@+id/buscar_instalaciones_horario_fragment_diasdelasemanaPicker"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TimePicker android:id="@+id/buscar_instalaciones_horario_fragment_timePicker" 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Now this is the screen:

[image]

As you can see, the two pickers are not aligned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this Piece of code

```
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_weight="2"
android:orientation="horizontal">

    <NumberPicker
                android:id="@+id/buscar_instalaciones_horario_fragment_diasdelasemanaPicker"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TimePicker android:id="@+id/buscar_instalaciones_horario_fragment_timePicker" 
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**edited:**

**Solved** by Adding this line in LinearLayout

```
android:gravity="center_vertical"
```

Comment: It isn' t solved. In Eclipse, in Graphical Layout is ok but in Devices no. [http://s15.postimg.org/beikv05i3/Hautapena_008.jpg](http://s15.postimg.org/beikv05i3/Hautapena_008.jpg)

Comment: The Style is correct but the data picker doesn' t work for me. I need [weekday - hour - minute]

Comment: android offers either date picker or time picker
you have to pic days and time than you have to design your own picker
this will help you to design and samples also there
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746624/day-of-week-and-time-picker-in-android-for-a-recurring-event

Comment: In Android Virtuak Machine whith 3.2 inches screen, the aling is ok. [http://s11.postimg.org/swptrvkoj/Hautapena_009.jpg](http://s11.postimg.org/swptrvkoj/Hautapena_009.jpg) . But in my device (5.5 inches) no.

Comment: Which alignment not seems good on 5.5 ? Left align right align ?

Comment: I don' t understand. Pickers have not align property.

Comment: There are three aliments, Left align, right align and center align, which alignment you want. and at this time picker is showing on which side ?

Comment: Solved. add this line `android:gravity="center_vertical"` in LinearLayout. Thank You very much @Assad

Comment: Your Always welcome. I was also asking that, now you have told that you wants  center align, Any ways Congrats! @aldakur